# Store application settings Tizen Native SDK

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk

Is there any good practice to store app setings data? 
I have allready tried:

```
void save_cfg(void *data)
{
FILE *file;
appdata_s* ad = (appdata_s*)data;

file = fopen("/opt/usr/apps/appID/data/cfg.txt", "w" );

fprintf(file, "%d\n%d", settings1, settings2);

fclose(file);
}
```

It seems to work but I dont see the file in file explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options, depending on your persistence requirements.

- [1. Preference API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__PREFERENCE__MODULE.html) - For simple key value pairs
- [2. SQlite API](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__OPENSRC__SQLITE__FRAMEWORK.html) - SQL DB
- [3. Standard C++ API](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++/api/) - File I/O API